# Django model field with default value from another model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a model like this:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Now i wanna have something like this:

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    aaa = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
    tar = models.Char(Field(max_length=255, default="")
    fo2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=???)
```

where i want `fo2` to take a value from `ModelA` unless other is provided.

How should i do that?

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Perhaps consider overriding the save method of ModelB that looks up the value of interest from ModelA instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you want the default value of `fo2` to equal to something related with the specific instance of `aaa` at creation?

The way to do that would be to override the `save` method

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    aaa = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
    tar = models.Char(Field(max_length=255, default="")
    fo2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.fo2 is None:
            self.fo2 = self.aaa._value_taken_from_Model_A
        super(ModelB, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```