# Referencing Attribute from Separate Class/Model

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

Using Django and PostgreSQL. I'm building a media streaming website. Where I have a Video class/model referencing back to a Broadcaster class/model.

I'm attempting to grab an attribute (name) from the Broadcaster class and reference it as either the default value or directly from the ForeignKey relationship.

Whenever I try to access/reference the attribute I get

`<django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey>`

[Picture of ForeignKey Jargon when referencing Video model/class attribute broadcaster_name. (default=broadcaster.name)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mSTZ.png)

**BUT** only when using video.broadcaster_name located in the Video class/model.

Instead of the attribute reference of `video.broadcaster.name`, which is the goal.

**Below is my Python/Django code:**

---

```
class Broadcaster(models.Model):
    member = models.OneToOneField(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

    def get_name(self):
        return f'{self.name}'
```

---

```
class Video(models.Model):
    broadcaster = models.ForeignKey(Broadcaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    broadcaster_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=broadcaster.name)
```

---

I've tried several different approaches with no avail...

Below is my HTML/Django code:

---

```
{% for video in media_list %}
        <div class="card">
            <img class="cover_img"
                 src="{{ video.cover_img_url }}"
                 alt="Cover Image">
            <p></p>

            <h2>{{ video.title }}</h2>  {# Works #}

        <h2>{{ video.broadcaster }}</h2>  {# Doesn't Work #}

          <h2>{{ video.broadcaster.get_name }}</h2>  {# Doesn't Work #}

        <h2>{{ video.broadcaster.name }}</h2>  {# Doesn't Work #}

        <h2>{{ video.broadcaster_name }}</h2>   {# Returns Object/ForeignKey Jargon #}
        </div>

    {% endfor %}
```

---

Similar questions have answered but none of the approaches worked for me. I've also reviewed Youtube, Google, and the Dango Docs (which was a bit confusing) for countless hours..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django model field with default value from another model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44421024/django-model-field-with-default-value-from-another-model)

Comment: Although do note, this is adding redundancy and making it more difficult for you to have _consistent_ data, i.e. now whenever you update `Broadcaster.name` you also have to update `Video.broadcaster_name` to make sure your data is consistent. This is going against the use of a foreign key itself. Why store this duplicate data when you can get it from the foreign key?

Comment: Thank you too much for trying to assist me!

Comment: I actually don't want to use the 'video.broadcaster_name' attribute, for that exact reason redundancy. I only have it listed because I was trying different methods of grabbing the data from the ForeignKey object/model (Broadcaster) but couldn't figure why it wasn't working.. I'm going to review over the link you posted and see if solves the problem but I'm a little doubtful because I believe I've tried the method listed in the link. I'm almost certain I'm using the keywords incorrectly (OneToOne, ForeignKey, null=True, blank=True)...